# Login with conflicting open id

Tags: support, login, user-experience

Here is the scenario.

For Stack Exchange, I use my personal Google account (open id) for logging in.

At work I am always logged into my work Google account.

When I try to login to SE, it always tries to log me in using my work Google account. So to log in correctly I always have to do this:

- Go to google.com and log out of my work account
- Go to SE and login using open id (which has a side effect of logging me into my personal google account)
- Go back to google.com and log out of my personal google account
- Log back into my work google account
- Go back to SE site

It is a lot of steps just to log in to SE without side effects.

Is there a better way?

I tried going to my SE profile and add another login, but it is only giving me more open id options, I would like to just setup a username/password I can use.

Comment: Why not just add your work gmail to the logins?

Answer (score 1):

[Our OpenID service](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) is kinda/sorta like setting up a username/password. I'm not 100% sure off the top of my head why we no longer offer it as an option for an additional login. I'll have to check.

There's [a workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/155160), but it's not exactly fully supported and you have to make sure you're already signed in when you start following it.

As another option in the meantime, you can [add your work Google credentials](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134379/how-can-i-link-two-google-accounts-to-one-stack-exchange-account) to your account. You'll need to enable multi-signin on Google side long enough to set this up, and you can turn it off right after.

Comment: I assumed the fact that the option to add an SE login was missing was a bug because removing it didn't make any answer.  If you find it isn't a bug and was an intentional decision, would someone be kind enough to respond to [Option to add a Stack Exchange Login to Existing Account has gone AWOL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234664/option-to-add-a-stack-exchange-login-to-existing-account-has-gone-awol)

Comment: @psubsee2003 I *believe* it was removed to make SE OpenID look more like a normal login/password (since it makes zero sense to have two of those). I'll raise this again internally next week. My personal opinion is that we should put it back so long as someone doesn't have another SE OpenID already associated with their profile. Supporting multiple ones per account is a bit weird on our end, and you can't even add another one if all you have signed in previously with is an SE OpenID since we don't support multi-signin.

Comment: I agree completely.  My experience suggests many users sign in with something familiar (like Google and Facebook) initially, but end up wanting an SE login after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Click The Drop Down To Remember your password. Then use a different browser to always be logged in to your other email. Your never more than three clicks away from your E-Mails.